# Trouble with pyodbc and file path names

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc

My troubles with pyodbc all started when I recently moved to a new PC that is 64-bit based.  Since then I have only got pyodbc to work if I hard code in a file path which I was hoping to avoid.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\\Users\\jf\\Documents\\TestDB.mdb;')
```

If I attempt to use a variable in place of manually typing in the file path of an Access database, I get HY000 error where it says Not a valid file name.  I think this has something to do with having a 64-bit machine and running 32-bit version of Office.  Any other ideas I could try in order to utilize a variable instead of hard coding the file path.  The variable allows me to quick change to the current directory I'm working in.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine:

```python
import pyodbc
fileSpec = r"C:\__tmp\foo.mdb"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + fileSpec)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT LastName FROM Clients WHERE ID=1")
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.LastName
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me too in a very simple example however, doesn't when I try to use it in my big script.  I continue to get the data source name not found message.  Strange thing is I can run the script no problem on a 32-bit machine.